# Create record by submitting string for reference field

Tags: rest-api

Is it possible to create an `Event` record through the rest API by the following;

Say the Event requires a reference field called `RecordTypeId` of type `reference`, but I only have the `RecordType.Name` not the `Id`. Is it possible to supply a name (string) value when creating an `Event` for this field without having to query the `RecordType` to find the `Id`?

I have only the `Name` (`string`) and want to create a record in a single request. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It appears it is possible by submitting:

`RecordType.Name: 'name string'`

and salesforce performs the appropriate lookup. The name happens to be unique in my case.